# SQL QUERY how to select column by other constraints

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack-crud controller for 
PHP-Laravel.

With the crudController given by backpack (library), all I have to do 
is to query it with Laravel Eloquent (also raw sql is possible) queries.

Than the Backpack library will automatically 
print the listview for me.

But I am struggling with this difficult query.

The thing is that I have 4 columns,

```
session_id | column_id | batch | data
10         | 1         | 1     | data1
10         | 2         | 1     | data2
10         | 1         | 2     | data1*
10         | 2         | 2     | data2*
```

Let's say this is the data I have.
I want to display this grouping by session_id, batch,
and ordering within row by column_id.

so the result query would be something like

```
1 :  data1   data2
2 : data1*  data2*
```

If there is a third batch with data

```
session_id | column_id | batch | data
10         | 1         | 3     | data1**
```

Then it would appear under the third batch as

```
3 : data1**
```

I can do this with code but not with sql.

Any advice would be grateful.

Comment: so there is no SQL Query?

Comment: @Akam That's what I'm asking

Comment: What you are asking is like [`PIVOT` in sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017). Unfortunately mysql does not have pivoting feature. But an approximate solution can be retrieved using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) in sql server. Unfortunately mysql does not have this feature.

I can give you an approximate raw mysql query using `GROUP_CONCAT`. Assuming your table name is `mytable`.

```
SELECT 
   session_id, 
   batch, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(data ORDER BY column_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS dataList 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY session_id, batch
```

Then you can split the aliased `dataList` column using given separator (here I've used `,`). 
You may change the separator according to the data contain in `data` column as you wish.

Hope this helps to you.